# Ubuntu 20.04 / FRITZ!Box 7490 / NetworkManager refuses to establish WiFi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager, ubuntu-20.04, fritzbox

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a ThinkPad T400. Every time I start the computer and it tries to connect to my router (AVM FRITZ!Box 7490) then the connection **fails** to establish multiple times. After about two minutes the connection can be established. Here is the the excerpt of the syslog.

```log
kernel: [  205.048521] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
NetworkManager[4054]: <warn>  [1610103773.5309] sup-iface[0x5596cafd4900,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103773.5310] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
dbus-daemon[1049]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.108' (uid=0 pid=4054 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
dbus-daemon[1049]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3762] policy: auto-activating connection 'MyRouter' (b1eb0a15-7618-4605-8ea5-4d047fa58ed9)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3782] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyRouter' (b1eb0a15-7618-4605-8ea5-4d047fa58ed9)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3825] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3835] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3891] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3947] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MyRouter' has security, but secrets are required.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3979] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.3986] sup-iface[0x5596cafd4900,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4058] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4168] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4177] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyRouter' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4178] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyRouter'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4178] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4178] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4178] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4179] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4179] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 (SSID='MyRouter' freq=5500 MHz)
kernel: [  207.979287] wlp3s0: authenticate with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06
kernel: [  207.981927] wlp3s0: send auth to 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.4528] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 (SSID='MyRouter' freq=5500 MHz)
kernel: [  208.064412] wlp3s0: authenticated
kernel: [  208.065382] wlp3s0: associate with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.5334] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
kernel: [  208.068463] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: Associated with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
kernel: [  208.071020] wlp3s0: associated
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.5452] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.5529] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
kernel: [  208.165305] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 completed [id=0 id_str=]
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.6520] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.6522] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MyRouter"
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.6525] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103776.6534] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
avahi-daemon[1044]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4.
avahi-daemon[1044]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
avahi-daemon[1044]: Registering new address record for fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4 on wlp3s0.*.
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-39 noise=9999 txrate=6000
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
NetworkManager[4054]: <warn>  [1610103821.4700] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): request timed out
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.4701] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.4703] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.4738] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[4054]: <warn>  [1610103821.4883] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyRouter'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.4890] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
avahi-daemon[1044]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4 on wlp3s0.
avahi-daemon[1044]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4.
avahi-daemon[1044]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.5138] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.5138] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed timeout -> done
kernel: [  253.061206] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=34:31:c4:3b:9a:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
dbus-daemon[1049]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.108' (uid=0 pid=4054 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
kdeconnectd.desktop[2328]: "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties” on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3"
systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
NetworkManager[4054]: <warn>  [1610103821.5696] sup-iface[0x5596cafd4900,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103821.5697] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
dbus-daemon[1049]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4015] policy: auto-activating connection 'MyRouter' (b1eb0a15-7618-4605-8ea5-4d047fa58ed9)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4023] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyRouter' (b1eb0a15-7618-4605-8ea5-4d047fa58ed9)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4024] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4029] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4035] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4043] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MyRouter' has security, but secrets are required.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4043] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4047] sup-iface[0x5596cafd4900,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4086] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4094] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4104] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyRouter' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4105] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyRouter'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4105] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4105] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4106] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4106] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4106] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 (SSID='MyRouter' freq=5500 MHz)
kernel: [  256.021600] wlp3s0: authenticate with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4
kernel: [  256.023965] wlp3s0: send auth to f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.4947] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 (SSID='MyRouter' freq=5500 MHz)
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.5314] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
kernel: [  256.062081] wlp3s0: authenticated
kernel: [  256.069507] wlp3s0: associate with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 (try 1/3)
kernel: [  256.072007] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: Associated with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
kernel: [  256.074602] wlp3s0: associated
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.5484] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.5566] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
kernel: [  256.162912] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 27 (30 - 3) dBm as advertised by f0:b0:14:42:df:e4
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f0:b0:14:42:df:e4 completed [id=0 id_str=]
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.6504] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.6505] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MyRouter"
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.6511] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.6523] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
avahi-daemon[1044]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4.
avahi-daemon[1044]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
avahi-daemon[1044]: Registering new address record for fe80::3ced:f668:f825:5de4 on wlp3s0.*.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.6999] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '864000'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7000] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option domain_name          => 'fritz.box'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7001] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.178.1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7001] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option expiry               => '1610967824'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7002] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.178.79'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7002] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option next_server          => '192.168.178.1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7002] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option ntp_servers          => '192.168.178.1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7003] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7003] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7004] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7004] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7004] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7005] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7005] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
avahi-daemon[1044]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.79.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7005] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7006] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7006] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7007] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7007] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7008] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7008] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7008] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7009] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7009] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7010] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option routers              => '192.168.178.1'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7010] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7010] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
avahi-daemon[1044]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
avahi-daemon[1044]: Registering new address record for 192.168.178.79 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7194] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7302] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7306] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7313] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7483] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7528] policy: set 'MyRouter' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7537] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103824.7564] manager: startup complete
kdeconnectd.desktop[2328]: kdeconnect.core: Broadcasting identity packet
systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
systemd-resolved[454]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.178.1.
wpa_supplicant[1109]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-47 noise=9999 txrate=13500
NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1610103825.7385] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
whoopsie[1741]: [12:03:49] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
whoopsie[1741]: [12:03:49] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
whoopsie[1741]: [12:03:49] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
whoopsie[1741]: [12:03:49] online
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
```

I can't see the reason for the error behavior. Can you? Is there any other log which might be useful for analyzing the problem?

Comment: The log seems to lack the first connect (followed by deauth). The `wpa_supplicant` probably managed to connect first. There are many reasons the local host would disconnect from WiFi. One of them is conflicting network configurators (like NetworkManager and another one). More could probably be read from the previous log lines.

Comment: I uploaded a new version of the syslog [here](https://hastebin.com/sufucayehu.yaml). I cannot paste it here - it is too long.